# How to convert an [Object Object] to an Array [] of key-value pairs in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object

the `userId`  contains,

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

i want to convert the above to array as follows.The `userId` actually contains as in below.

```
[{"user_id":"aaa@gmail.com","slno":1}, 
{"user_id":"bbb@gmail.com","slno":2}, 
{"user_id":"cccc@gmail.com","slno":3}, 
{"user_id":"ddd@gmail.com","slno":4}]
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Can you put the data that comes from the server and you want to convert it to previuse state clearly?

Comment: What did you tried ? Can you put the code giving Object Object ?

Comment: at server side it  converts the list to array by `$newArray = json_decode($userId);`  but after it  the `newArray` will be  empty.i need to convert the contents in `[object object]` to a key-value pair array as in initial state

Comment: We don't need your server side code. We just need the data that comes from the sever and you want to convert it. If you want to modify your server side you have to tag PHP not react native.

Comment: We need the data that you passed which I think is present in the question and we also need the data that you receive from the server and you want to change.

Comment: @Reza i dont need to server side; passed data is a set of userids( email format). the data is in object form  i need to convert as array=> `{"user_id":"aaa@gmail.com","slno":1}, 
{"user_id":"bbb@gmail.com","slno":2}, 
{"user_id":"cccc@gmail.com","slno":3}, 
{"user_id":"ddd@gmail.com","slno":4}]`

Comment: @Fahad: Is it working?